# Need to make parent class active when child is clicked or submenu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have header with menus which is included in all pages. The problem is when I am clicking on submenu I am unable to make the submenu and it's parent menu highlighted or active.

```js
$(".dropdown .dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
  $(".active").removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('a:first').addClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="builders">Builders<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="gurgaon.php">Gurgaon</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>all-india" class="active">All India</a></li>
      <li><a href="gurgaon-projects.php">Gurgaon Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/property_list">Property List</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *submenu and it's parent* which tags are submenu and parent?

Comment: suppose if gurgaon page is clicked it's parent a builders should be also highlight.

Comment: Please include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We will need to see HTML and JS and CSS.

Comment: jquery: <script>
$(".dropdown .dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
 //alert('anu');
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('a:first').addClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
</script>

Comment: Please use the 'edit' button under your question to add code, as it's not easily readable in comments. I've done it for you in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code works, you just need to also make it run on load as well as `click`, which you can do by using `trigger('click')`:

```js
var $a = $(".dropdown .dropdown-menu li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // just for testing...
  $(".active").removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('a:first').addClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
$a.filter('.active').trigger('click');
```

```css
.active {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="builders">Builders<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="gurgaon.php">Gurgaon</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>all-india" class="active">All India</a></li>
      <li><a href="gurgaon-projects.php">Gurgaon Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/property_list">Property List</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="builders">Builders<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="gurgaon.php">Gurgaon</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>all-india">All India</a></li>
      <li><a href="gurgaon-projects.php">Gurgaon Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>home/property_list">Property List</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is working but then I am unable to open the page...suppose all india. It's just highlighting the head

Comment: That's because I added the `e.preventDefault()` call in there for this example, you need to remove that then perform whatever logic you require on the click of the `a` element.

Comment: I have removed that but by default active class is not removed from all india. when I am clicking another list item

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, the following code will add the desired class name to the parent with the specified class name.

```
document.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {

  const closestDropDown = target.closest('.dropdown');

  if(closestDropDown){
    closestDropDown.classList.add('active');
    console.log(closestDropDown);
  }
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You mean if I use a jQuery selector? Element.closest() returns a general Element object which definitely has the classList property. Or am I missing something? :O